# How can I include examples in library?

Tags: library

I have written a library for Arduino, `my_library`, consisting of `my_library.h` and `my_library.cpp`, both included in `my_library` folder. Actually the library is recognized from IDE Arduino and works fine.

I want to add some examples, let's say `Example1` and `Example2`. How is that possible?

Should the examples be included in `my_library` folder?

or should be included in another folder inside `my_library` folder?

I tried several combinations but none worked. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a folder called "examples" in your library folder. Within there, each in its own folder, you place your examples.

For example:

```
MyLib/
MyLib/MyLib.h
MyLib/MyLib.cpp
MyLib/examples/
MyLib/examples/Example1/
MyLib/examples/Example1/Example1.ino
MyLib/examples/Example2/
MyLib/examples/Example2/Example2.ino
```

Be sure to name the example's folder the same as the name of the example.